# How to restrict awk number of fields?

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

Below is my test file.

```
aa, bb, cc
dd, ee
ff, gg, hh
```

Is it possible to make `awk` think we only have 2 fields for each record and the record separator is the first `,`? So in my example, the `$2` for each record is:

```
bb, cc
ee
gg, hh
```

Comment: Probably easier to pre-process this with another awk / sed script to remove extra comma's

Comment: I don't think there's any. Use `sub` instead: `awk '{sub(/^[^,]*, */,"")} {print}'`

Comment: `awk -F'(^[^,]*, *)' '{ print $2 }' infile`

Comment: @αғsнιη This really works! Could you explain a little bit about the regex? I can't fully understand it. `^` always matches the start of the record, does that mean the field separator always at the beginning of the record? I don't quite understand.

Comment: that sets the field seperator to a string that it starts from the beginning of a record upto first comma and including trailing spaces. `[^,]*,` matches every character that it's not a comma until first comma seen.

Answer (score 3):

Done by below method and it worked fine

From Above question i understood it should consider $2 and $3 as $2 only

command

```
awk -F " " '{$2=$2$3;print $1,$2}' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `Perl` by specifying the number of fields you want your current record to be split into. In your case it is 2.

The `-F` option will split into two fields the current record `$_` using the comma as delimiter.

```
$ perl -F'/,/,$_,2' -lane '
    print "\$0=<<$_>>";
    print "\$1=<<$F[0]>> \$2=<<$F[1]>>", "\n";
' file.csv
```

You could also use the `read` builtin of bash gainfully here by giving two arguments to it :

```
  while IFS=, read -r f1 f2; do
     # $1 = f1 $2 = f2
  done < file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this if you just cram all fields after `$2` into `$2`.

```
awk '
  BEGIN{ FS=","; OFS=";" }
  {
    for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
      $2 = $2","$i
    }
  }
  { print $1,$2 }
 ' data.txt
```

Will give you these results:

```
aa; bb, cc
dd; ee
ff; gg, hh
```